# Selecting entries of a sub array

Tags: json, jq

I have json that looks like:

```
{
  "base": "abc",
  "members" : [
            {"fn": "maurice", "ln": "hickey"},
            {"fn": "john", "ln": "smith"},
            {"fn": "robin", "ln": "smith"},
            ...
          ],
  "date": "2018-08-26"
}
```

I am trying to write a jq filter to give me the same schema output but with only a subset of the members array e.g. all the "smith"s

```
{
  "base": "abc",
  "members" : [
            {"fn": "john", "ln": "smith"},
            {"fn": "robin", "ln": "smith"}
          ],
  "date": "2018-08-26"
}
```

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you specifically looking for a jquery filter or can you use a JavaScript/es6 filter?

Comment: Hi Chris - thanks for responinding, I am specifically looking for a jq (https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) filter as a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This gets the desired output.

```
jq '.members |= map(select(.ln == "smith"))'
```

It updates .members, selecting only objects with .ln == smith